# Can't create the tables because the primary keys used as foreign keys in another table

Tags: sql-server

```
Create Table Customer 
(
    Cus_id Varchar2(10) NOT NULL Primary Key,
    Cus_FirstName Varchar2(20) NOT NULL,
    Cus_LastName Varchar2 (20) NOT NULL,
    Cus_Address Varchar2(25) NOT NULL,
    Cus_City_State_Zip Varchar2(30) NOT NULL
);

Create Table Order_ 
(
    Order_id Varchar2(10) NOT NULL Primary Key,
    Order_Date Varchar2(12) NOT NULL,
    Order_Status Varchar(12) NOT NULL
);

Create Table Item 
(
    Item_id Varchar2(10) NOT NULL Primary Key,
    Item_Name Varchar2(20) NOT NULL,
    Item_Price Varchar2(10) NOT NULL
);

Create Table CustomerOrderItem 
(
    Quantity Varchar2(8) NOT NULL, 
    Cus_id Varchar(10) NOT NULL Primary Key,
    Order_id Varchar(10) NOT NULL Primary Key, 
    Item_id Varchar(10) NOT NULL Primary Key,
    Foreign Key(Cus_id) References Customer(Cus_id),
    Foreign Key(Oreder_id) References Order_(Order_id),
    Foreign Key(Item_id) References Item(Item_id)
);
```

This code is a customer table with repeated orders and multiple items for one order. When I try to insert values into the table and create them. I created the fourth table due to their dependency and put three primary keys there as primary keys and foreign keys. It does not let me create the tables saying because the primary keys used as foreign keys in another table, therefore I need to drop them first to create the tables.

Comment: There is a code formatting option in the editor "{}" please use it. Or 3 backticks.

Comment: That doesn't look like SQL Server, which doesn't have a `varchar2` data type.

Comment: Oracle has a varchar2 data type. Are you using Oracle?

Comment: Since when SQL Server has data type `VARCHAR2`?  Maybe start by tagging your question properly.

Answer (score 2):

Your data schema neither matches what you describe, nor is a correct syntax for SQL Server. Putting aside the bad design, this is what you are trying to do:

```
Create Table Customer ( Cus_id Varchar(10) NOT NULL Primary Key, 
  Cus_FirstName Varchar(20) NOT NULL, 
  Cus_LastName Varchar (20) NOT NULL, 
  Cus_Address Varchar(25) NOT NULL, 
  Cus_City_State_Zip Varchar(30) NOT NULL );

Create Table Order_ ( Order_id Varchar(10) NOT NULL Primary Key, 
   Order_Date Varchar(12) NOT NULL, 
   Order_Status Varchar(12) NOT NULL );

Create Table Item ( Item_id Varchar(10) NOT NULL Primary Key, 
  Item_Name Varchar(20) NOT NULL, 
  Item_Price Varchar(10) NOT NULL );

Create Table CustomerOrderItem ( Quantity Varchar(8) NOT NULL, 
  Cus_id Varchar(10) NOT NULL, 
  Order_id Varchar(10) NOT NULL, 
  Item_id Varchar(10) NOT NULL,
constraint PK_CustomerOrderItem primary key (cus_id, order_id, item_id), 
constraint FK_COI_Customer Foreign Key(Cus_id) References Customer(Cus_id), 
constraint FK_COI_Order Foreign Key(Order_id) References Order_(Order_id), 
constraint FK_COI_Item Foreign Key(Item_id) References Item(Item_id) );
```

Check Northwind sample database for a better sample, and for even a better one check AdventureWorks sample database as starters.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. When I triy to drop the previous one to create the tables it says: -
ORA-02449: unique/primary keys in table referenced by foreign keys
02449. 00000 -  "unique/primary keys in table referenced by foreign keys"
*Cause:    An attempt was made to drop a table with unique or
           primary keys referenced by foreign keys in another table.
*Action:   Before performing the above operations the table, drop the
           foreign key constraints in other tables.

Comment: @Hass, that is an Oracle message, but you tagged the question with MS SQL Server. Anyway, first drop the tables with foreign keys referencing those tables.

Answer (score 0):

the Error message you got ORA-02449 is due to trying to drop a table that is already referenced as primary key in CustomerOrderItem  table ,to solve this issue drop the CustomerOrderItem table first then drop the other tables afterwards.
Good luck.